# Google TV emulator won't start

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-tv

I followed this [Google TV Emulation guide](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator), which tells how to set up my emulator environment. Although when I launch the AVD created by AVD manager, the emulator starts but no logo appears and a black screen. One of my CPU cores is always 100 percent; KVM is enabed. The -verbose option log ends with the following lines:

```
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /media/Mywork/tools/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /media/Mywork/tools/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms
```

My host envrionment is: Intel i7, Ubuntu  10.04 64-bit.

Comment: which SDK version are you using?

Comment: are you trying this from Eclipse? If its from command line...what command are you trying?

Comment: You might consider writing me lesv (at) google (dot) com

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the settings for your AVD?

Edit: 
Also, have you tried pushing an app into the emulator? 
Can you include the steps you used to launch the emulator?
Did you apt-get install kvm?